# How to Determine Certain Characters in a Variable Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to find if the first three characters of the variable $Fullname1 contain a letter "e." The code I am using is this:

`if ((substr($Fullname1, 0, 3)) eq 'e'){
    print "The first three letters contain an e.\n";
}else { print "The first three letters do not contain an e.\n";}`

It doesn't seem to be working. Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

People tend to forget about the good old `index()` function.

```
    index STR,SUBSTR
        The index function searches for one string within another, but
        without the wildcard-like behavior of a full regular-expression
        pattern match.
```

So this is a direct solution to this particular problem (for extremely high volume it's also a teeny bit faster, but for normal applications that won't make a difference):

```
if ( index(substr($Fullname1, 0, 3), 'e') != -1){
```

Answer (score 3):

Your original code

```
if ((substr($Fullname1, 0, 3)) eq 'e')
```

compares a string consisting of 3 characters (or less, if `$Fullname1` is shorter than 3 chars) to a single character `'e'`, which always fails.

This:

```
if ( substr( $FullName1, 0, 3 ) =~ /e/ )
```

makes a string of the first 3 (or less) characters, and then applies a regular expression `/e/`, which matches a single letter `e` in any position of the string.

Check out `man perlre` for more information.

Comment: This might benefit from a little more explanation - to clarify why `=~ /e/` is a very different operation from `eq 'e'`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a regex to check whether the variable contains zero, one, or two characters followed by an `e`. Like this

```
if ( $Fullname1 =~ /\A.{0,2}e/s ) {

    print "The first three letters contain an e.\n";
}
else {

    print "The first three letters do not contain an e.\n";
}
```